# Bullseye coverage error message

Tags: linux, jenkins, bullseye

I have a jenkins build job that runs a Bullseye coverage report that was working fine until last week. Found out our build server had been updated to a newer linux kernel version and started seeing this issue now.

Anyone have any ideas what could be the root cause of problem?

> drivers/BullseyeCoverage/libcov-linuxKernel.c: In function
>   ‘notifier_callback’:
>   drivers/BullseyeCoverage/libcov-linuxKernel.c:108:54: error: ‘const
>   struct module’ has no member named ‘module_core’
>       const unsigned long modBegin = (unsigned long)module->module_core;
>                                                         ^ drivers/BullseyeCoverage/libcov-linuxKernel.c:109:48: error: ‘const
>   struct module’ has no member named ‘core_size’
>       const unsigned long modEnd = modBegin + module->core_size;
>                                                   ^ error: status 1 from /usr/local/arm/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc make[1]: ***
>   [drivers/BullseyeCoverage/libcov-linuxKernel.o] Error 1 make: ***
>   [drivers/BullseyeCoverage] Error 2

Comment: Could you share any relevant code?

Comment: Its clear some error in building some kernel module fails as some field ins struct `module` is missing. Check if theres any updates you could get for that tool. If those sources are proprietary your best bet is to contact support is guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like Dominik you were correct. Looks like when we updated from version 4.4 to 4.5 that /kernel/module.c in version 4.5 no longer has "module_core" or "core_size" in it.